# Countably Infinite Cross Product.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $A$ be countably infinite and $B = \{x,y\}$.
 How do I prove that $A×B=\{(a,b):a∈A,b∈B\}$ is countably infinite?

I understand that we must show that there is a one to one correspondence from A x B to $Z^+$

So the question becomes, is there a function $f:Z^+$ to (A x B) that is one to one and onto. This is the part I do not understand.

Comment: You need to tell us what $A$ and $B$ are.

Comment: If $A=\{1,2,3\}$ and $B=\{4,5,6\}$, it's obvious that that's not countably infinite.

Comment: @LoganClark what if he is posting from the twilight zone?

Comment: If $B=\{x,y\}$, $B$ is definitely not countably infinite as it only has two elements.

Comment: So I need to show there is a function f from (AxB) to Z+ that is one-to-one and onto. I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: Can you make a sequence of all of the elements in $A\times B$ knowing that you can make a sequence of all of the elements in $A$?

Comment: Or maybe f from Z+ to (AxB)

Comment: Let $f:\mathbb{N}\to A$  be a bijection. Then $g:\mathbb{N}\to A\times B$ defined by $g(2n)=(f(n),x)$ and $g(2n+1)=(f(n),y)$ is a bijection.

Comment: Isn't "Cartesian product" a more usual term for this operation than "cross product"?

Comment: Where does the 2n and 2n-1 come from

Answer (score 1):

Since $A$ is countably infinite, there exists a bijection from $A$ to $\mathbb Z^+,$ which assigns a positive integer to every element of $A,$ so that $A$ can be written as $A = \{a_1, a_2, a_3, \dotsc\}.$
Now we have that
$$
A \times B = \{(a_1,x), (a_2,x), \dotsc, (a_1,y), (a_2,y), \dotsc\}
$$
and the bijection $f: A \times B \to \mathbb Z^+$ defined by
$$
f(a_n,x) = 2n - 1 \quad f(a_n,y) = 2n
$$
will be sufficient.

Comment: Thank you for being so straight forward in your answering!

Comment: Where do you get the 2n-1 and 2n from. I understand everything up until that point.

Comment: You're welcome!
We want a bijection, so we need to pair up every positive integer with an element of $A \times B.$ I just chose to associate the elements of the form $(a_n, y)$ with the even numbers ($2n$), and the elements of the form $(a_n, x)$ with the odd numbers ($2n -1,$ since I'm starting from $1$ and not from $0$).

Comment: I could have chosen any other bijection (say, $f : A \times B \to \mathbb Z$ where the elements with second term $x$ get associated to a negative integer and those with second term $y$ get associated to a non-negative integer); I chose even and odds because you wanted to "count" the elements using the positive integers, but a bijection onto $\mathbb Z$ works as well (why?).